# How to decrease picture size

Tags: css, images

On [my website](https://union.ic.ac.uk/rcc/firstaid/), how can I decrease the size of the picture with the cyclists? Currently, I think it's too big.

Comment: Do you mean size in bytes or dimensions?

Comment: to keep the image full width the quickest way would be to crop the image narrower. to do that use a image editor or you can do it from inside the wp admin

Comment: @N00b dimensions wise

Comment: @YobdDigital the image was inserted via the customise theme option and I think the theme is auto re-sizing the picture. Is there a line of CSS code I could change to decrease the dimensions?

Comment: I have added the css you would need as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to add this css to a child theme or install a custom css plugin

```
.blackwell_top_image {
    height:400px; //change this to whatever height you want the image to be
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It has to be done this way as the image width is set to 100% so setting a height on the image itself would distort the image. So we are adding the css to the parent container and hiding the rest of the image.

Comment: Can I add this to the Simple Custom CSS plugin I have?

Comment: yes you should be able to

Comment: Hi, it didn't work sadly. :( The image remains the same size as before but the three green icons below the picture move upwards and overlap with the picture.

Comment: dont take it off and i will look

Comment: Also note I have this currently in the Custom CSS to hide an annoying default blog post 

.home_blog_wrapper {
display: none;
}

Comment: HI, I re ran the code. PLease have a look now. The image boundary region is smaller but the image hasn't been resized properly?

Comment: the css you added appears to have worked. here is a screenshot of what i see when I view the page: http://pasteboard.co/fy8QtJ1.png

Comment: That's right, but I was hoping to be able to see the entire picture as before but just in a smaller framework. Does that make sense? The picture frame is smaller as I want but the actual picture is cut off... I can't see the bikes in the picture.

Comment: this is what I said was the problem in the beginning. as the image width is set to be 100% of the browser window, no matter how wide the window is, if you set a smaller height on the image it would be squashed. to see what I mean add this css `#top_image_full .top_image_container li img {height: 400px !important;} `

Comment: I see... Managed to fix it by adding some white space to the bottom of the picture :) Cheers for your help from SJA!

Comment: no problem. glad I could help